# Delphi dynamic array working like ListItem in a ListView

Tags: delphi, dynamic-arrays

I like ListViews.  In fact, I will go so much as to say that I love ListViews.  So easy to use, especially with adding new items, deleting items, counting items, and running through all of the items.

I would like to create a dynamic array that I can manage in pretty much the same way.

Something like this:

- You add new items using code like ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
- You can reference items similar to ListView1.Items.Item[i]
- You can remove items using code like ListItem.Free (or ListView1.Items.Item[i].Free), and it automatically re-indexes the remaining items
- You can count the items like ListView1.Count

Does anybody have a "template" of a non visual component that will give the same kind of functionality for adding items, removing items and counting items within the dynamic aray?

Or, are there non-visual components which exist which I could inherit to give me the functionality I seek?

Comment: Do you mean [TObjectlist](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectList_(Delphi))?

Comment: Its been a while since I touched Delphi but is an [ArrayList](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/NameSpace.asp?Name=System.Collections&Part=ArrayList) not roughly what you are looking for?

Comment: See the docs at [Working with Lists](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Working_with_Lists) for a fairly complete description of the list-type classes that are part of Delphi itself (all of which are "non-visual").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Generics.Collections](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections) unit. It consists of a number of classes you are looking for. Especially, [TObjectList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectList_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: This would only apply if he's using Delphi 2010 onwards.

Comment: I think this would be what I am looking for, from the outside, regrettably, Embarcadero's examples make use of < > which I have never seen inside Delphi code before.  Usually, < > represents "replace with something relevant", but I can't seem to get my code to work, despite copying and pasting Embarcadero code as is.

I will ask another question relating to TObjectList (after doing some googling).  Thanks for the answer, I think it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @KeyszerS, you did not specifiy your Delphi version so we assume you have the latest version. for Pre D2010 you can find the non generic version of TObjectList in the Contnrs unit.

Comment: To understand < > Google 'Delphi generics'